# How does work the goals including a funnel?

Tags: google-analytics

### We have setup a funnel and the destination using Regular Expressions:

- Funnel RegEx: **-[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-STRATEX-MLCHIMP-.***
- Destination RegEx: **/(Activity|Event|Project|Contract|Proposal|RequestForOffer)/Details/[0-9]+**

[image: Setup Goal on Google Analytics]

### Here is the URL shared inside our newsletter

https://www.stratexapp.com/?utm_source=StratEx+new+features+Newsletter&utm_campaign=2c3cbe636b-2017-03-29-STRATEX-MLCHIMP-EditCoAuthorOfficeFiles&utm_medium=email&utm_term=0_bf4b36a4fb-2c3cbe636b-174623477

## To ease the reading, here are the URL' parameters

- ?**utm_source**=StratEx+new+features+Newsletter
- &**utm_campaign**=2c3cbe636b-2017-03-29-STRATEX-MLCHIMP-EditCoAuthorOfficeFiles
- &**utm_medium**=email
- &**utm_term**=0_bf4b36a4fb-2c3cbe636b-174623477

---

### QUESTION 1: Why does Google Analytics counts every Goal EVEN if the visitor HAS NOT visited the Funnel?

Calling directly an URL matching the **Destination regex** increases the amount of Goals :-(

### QUESTION2: Is it correct to believe that Google Analytics matches ALL RegEx (Funnel AND Destination) to compute the goals?

### QUESTION3: Is it correct to believe that Google Analytics DOES NOT match ALL RegEx (Funnel OR Destination) to compute the goals?

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The configured funnel steps are only relevant for the funnel visualisation.  The goal will be counted regardless any time somebody reaches the destination.

So the answer to question two is no, Google Analytics does not look at the funnels at all to calculate goal conversions. Rather (question three) it ignores the funnel (except for the purpose of the funnel visualisation) when it calculates goal conversions.

Also a goal conversion is counted only once per session (i.e. a user cannot convert twice for the same goal within the same session).